# Using MariaDB in test environment and sql server in production, how to use use one select for both? - Java, Spring

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, mariadb

I hope my title wasn't too ambiguous - I'll try to elaborate through an example.

Given the sql that's going to be run in a repository somewhere:

private final String someQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 FROM someTable WHERE id = someIndex";

This runs in production but in integration tests I'd like to test towards a test database running MariaDB, how would I write that integration test without duplicating the select with limit 1 instead, and injecting it to the repository?

P.S If this is a duplicate question, I apologize - albeit I couldn't find issues of resemblance.

- Srs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions:

1) Put your queries in properties files and have different properties files for prod and dev.

2) Use JPA and the driver (probably hibernate) will take care of the SQL syntax.

3)  I would think about an H2 database for test.